# frindly routing in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am doing a website in joomla 3.0, I have select a friendly URi in the backend.
I create several componente for the website too, and my route to access to this component is like this.

```
<?php $link =JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_projects&view=proyectos&format=raw&task=proyecto&id='. $item->id);?>
```

But when the browser show this router it isn´t friendly router.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a router.php file for your component to tell joomla how to build the sef url and then parse it when the sef url is requested.

Check out the components/weblinks/router.php file for an example.

Alternatively, if you are using a sef component like joomsef or sh404sef, you will need to create a plugin for your component. You can find documentation on how to do this on the component makers websites.